# Delete data-id attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am new on javascript yet. I trying to delete value with data-id button, but data-id value is get always first value on my table. I click on the button with the data-id of "5" but as the id it is "1" (the topmost id) every time. Sorry my bad english.

My table codes:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Management</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><span class="label label-success">@item.ID</span></td>
                <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
                <td>@if (item.Status == true)
                    {
                        <b class="label label-success">Active</b>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <b class="label label-danger">Passive</b>
                    }
                    </td>
                <td><a href="#">@item.User.Name</a></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btn-Delete" onclick="DeleteCategory()" data-id="@item.ID">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript codes:

```
function DeleteCategory() {
    var caughtID= $("#btn-Delete").attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Category/Delete/" + caughtID,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.Success) {
                bootbox.alert(response.Message, function () {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }
            else {
                bootbox.alert(response.Message, function () {
                    //it's null yet
                });
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Id` need to be unique, but in your case without `id` also it can be achievable, what you want to do.

Change:-

```
onclick="DeleteCategory()"
```

To:-

```
onclick="DeleteCategory(this)"
```

And then:-

```
function DeleteCategory(ele) {
 var caughtID= $(ele).data("id");
 .....rest code
```

***DEMO EXAMPLE:-***

```js
function DeleteCategory(ele){
  alert($(ele).data('id'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btn-Delete" onclick="DeleteCategory(this)" data-id="1">Delete</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btn-Delete" onclick="DeleteCategory(this)" data-id="2">Delete</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btn-Delete" onclick="DeleteCategory(this)" data-id="3">Delete</button>
```

***A pure jQuery solution is:-***

change `id="btn-Delete"` to `class ="btn-Delete"` and remove `onclick` like below:-

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-Delete"  data-id="@item.ID">Delete</button>
```

And then change only this line:-

```
var caughtID= $("#btn-Delete").attr("data-id");
```

To:-

```
var caughtID = $(this).data("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rory commented ***id attributes must be unique!***. You should change the id of the button to class and make click on the static element. Because the button is dynamically created it may cause a problem that you are facing.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-Delete" data-id="@item.ID">Delete</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('table').on('click', '.btn-Delete', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var caughtID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Category/Delete/" + caughtID,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.Success) {
                bootbox.alert(response.Message, function() {
                    location.reload();
                });
            } else {
                bootbox.alert(response.Message, function() {
                    //it's null yet
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
});
```